# IEEEtran bibliography: URL containing dash/hyphen causes problem

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran

Whenever there is a URL containing dash/hyphen characters in my bibliography file, I get the following type of error:

> LaTeX Warning: Citation `wright2006' on page 1 undefined on input line 29.
>
> (./Untitled.bbl ./Untitled.bbl:29: Missing $ inserted.
>
> ```
>             $ l.29 ...l{https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-27925-3_2}
> ```

I figured that if I erase the URL field, there is no problem. The thing is that I have a large `bib` file containing more than 300 entries that will be cited. Most of them contain URL fields with dash/hyphen characters. I tested citations with URL fields that do not contain dash/hyphen characters and they work fine. How can I make this work without having to go through the whole file and erase more than 300 URL fields?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@inbook{wright2006,
    Address = {New York, NY},
    Author = {Wright, Kenneth W.},
    Booktitle = {Handbook of Pediatric Strabismus and Amblyopia},
    Date-Added = {2017-09-11 00:07:41 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-09-11 00:08:45 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1007/0-387-27925-3_2},
    Editor = {Wright, Kenneth W. and Spiegel, Peter H. and Thompson, Lisa S.},
    Isbn = {978-0-387-27925-1},
    Keywords = {Anatomy;Biology;anatomical data;physiology;Eyes;eye movements;biological data},
    Pages = {24--69},
    Publisher = {Springer New York},
    Title = {Anatomy and Physiology of Eye Movements},
    Url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-27925-3_2},
    Year = {2006},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\title{This document}
\author{This author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

I have cited this document \cite{wright2006}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to what you wrote in the title of your posting, it's not the hyphens in the `url` and `doi` fields that are giving you grief. Instead, it's the underscore characters: `_`. You need to load the `url` package, preferably with the option `hyphens`, in the preamble. That way, TeX and BibTeX won't try to interpret `_` as the initiator of subscript material in a url or doi string.

A separate issue: it's not correct to use the entry type `@inbook` for the entry at hand. Use `@incollection` instead.

Finally, the name of the bibliography style is `IEEEtran`, not `ieeetran`.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@incollection{wright2006,
    Author = {Wright, Kenneth W.},
    Title  = {Anatomy and Physiology of Eye Movements},
    Editor = {Wright, Kenneth W. and Spiegel, Peter H. and Thompson, Lisa S.},
    Booktitle= {Handbook of Pediatric Strabismus and Amblyopia},
    Pages    = {24-69},
    Address  = {New York, NY},
    Publisher= {Springer},
    url      = {https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-27925-3_2},
    Year     = {2006},
    Date-Added    = {2017-09-11 00:07:41 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-09-11 00:08:45 +0000},
    Doi      = {10.1007/0-387-27925-3_2},
    Isbn     = {978-0-387-27925-1},
    Keywords = {Anatomy;Biology;anatomical data;physiology;Eyes;eye movements;biological data},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % <--- new

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{wright2006}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```